# DICOM files to NRRD

Tags: bash, shell

I want to convert DICOM files to NRRD format using shell scripting one after another from one folder. Can anyone please help? I have tried some lines ,but the execution returns no good result.

Comment: Show us the code that has problems.

Comment: Please show your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve